# How to run official Tensorflow Docker Image as a non root user?

Tags: docker, tensorflow, deep-learning, dockerfile

I currently run the official Tensorflow Docker Container (GPU) with Nvidia-Docker:

- https://hub.docker.com/r/tensorflow/tensorflow/
- https://gcr.io/tensorflow/tensorflow/

However, I can't find a way to set a default user for the container. The default user for this container is "**root**", which is dangerous in term of security and problematic because it gives root access to the *shared folders*.

Let's say my host machine run with the user "*CNNareCute*", is there any way to launch my containers with the same user ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Docker containers by default run as `root`. You can override the user by passing `--user <user>` to docker run command. Note however this might be problematic in case the container process needs root access inside the container.

The security concern you mention is handled in docker using [User Namespaces](https://docs.docker.com/engine/security/userns-remap/). Usernamespaces basically map users in the container to a different pool of users on the host. Thus you can map the root user inside the container to a normal user on the host and the security concern should be mitigated.

Comment: User namespaces seem to perfectly answer my needs, do you have any idea on how to map "root" to "CNNareCute" user ?

Comment: There are many tutorial online such as https://success.docker.com/article/Introduction_to_User_Namespaces_in_Docker_Engine and https://www.jujens.eu/posts/en/2017/Jul/02/docker-userns-remap/. Basically, the remapping is done on the range, so find the uid of user `CNNareCute` using `cat /etc/passwd` and assign that as the start of the range in `/etc/subuid` example: `USER:<id of CNNareCute >:65536`. That way user 0 in container (root) will map to `CNNareCute` user on host

Answer (score 1):

AFAIK, docker images run by default as root. This means that any Dockerfile using the image as a base, doesn't have to jump through hoops to modify it. You could carry out user modification in a Dockerfile - same way you would on any other linux box which would give you the configuration you need.

You won't be able to use users (dynamically) from your host in the containers without creating them in the container first - and they will be in effect separate users of the same name.

You can run commands and ssh into containers as a specific user provided it exists on the container. For example, a PHP application needing commands run that retain `www-data` privileges, would be run as follows:

`docker exec --user www-data application_container_1 sh -c "php something"`

So in short, you can set up whatever users you like and use them to run scripts but the default will be root and it will exist unless you remove it which may also have repercussions...